# what is free registration components in joomla?

Tags: joomla1.6

I am using joomla 1.6.3 version . Now i need to enter some form data from front page and administrator can view, edit and delete that data.

For the above task any components available in joomla 1.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

I've had very good luck using the free RSForm! component. Very flexible and very customizable. It is technically written for Joomla 1.5, but you shouldn't have any problems running it under version 1.6

http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-components/rsform.html